# InverseProperty with Database Migration doesn't work when property is protected or internal

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-5

I have the following Entity Models

```
public class User
{
        public virtual long Id{get; set;}
        [InverseProperty("Users")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; protected set; } 
}

public class Tag
{
        public virtual long Id{get; set;}
        internal protected virtual ICollection<User> Users { get;  set; }
}
```

This is pure simple many-to-many relation User & Tag
I'm using Data Migrations. When I execute the command Add-Migration or Update-Database
I get the following error "The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Tags' on type 'Kigg.DomainObjects.Entities.User' is not valid. The property 'Users' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'Kigg.DomainObjects.Entities.Tag'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property."

When I changed the access modifier of Users property in Tag to public it worked fine and the generation is what I want.

From my design point of view I want to hide the Tag.Users property and make it protected or internal to keep it for internal use as I don't want to expose it to public API.

**Note: I'm not discussing the my design here. I'm asking if it's possible to do that while Tag.Users is protected or internal?**

Comment: It should be possible to target non-public properties with data annotations since EF 4.3 but I think this feature somehow doesn't work. Prior to EF 4.3 it wasn't possible at all.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes it is possible. The problem is with Database Migration. Running Update-Database or Add-Migration produce the above error mentioned in my question

Comment: I've achieved what I wanted to do using Fluent API with Data Migrations. But still curious to see if it is possible using Data Annotation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to make it work with data annotations but with Fluent API you can apply and experiment with the trick from here: http://blog.cincura.net/232731-mapping-private-protected-properties-in-entity-framework-4-x-code-first/

For your model it would look like the following:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual long Id{get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; protected set; } 
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual long Id{get; set;}
    internal protected virtual ICollection<User> Users { get;  set; }

    public class PropertyAccessors
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<Tag, ICollection<User>>> Users
            = t => t.Users;
    }
}
```

Mapping in FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Tags)
    .WithMany(Tag.PropertyAccessors.Users);
```

This works and creates the expected many-to-many relationship.

But I am not sure if you can do anything useful with that navigation property. The fact that you have the property `protected` and `virtual` lets me guess that you basically want lazy loading support inside of the entity class or derived classes.

The problem is that apparently (according to my tests at least) lazy loading doesn't work for anything else than a `public` property. The loaded tag is a proxy but the navigation collection is always `null` (unless the property is `public`).

Moreover, even eager and explicit loading don't work:

Outside of the `Tag` class:

```
// Eager loading
var tag = context.Tags.Include(Tag.PropertyAccessors.Users).First();

// Explicit loading
var tag2 = context.Tags.First();
context.Entry(tag2).Collection(Tag.PropertyAccessors.Users).Load();
```

Or inside of the `Tag` class (some method in `Tag` which gets the context passed):

```
public DoSomething(MyContext context)
{ 
    // Eager loading
    var tag = context.Tags.Include(t => t.Users).First();

    // Explicit loading
    context.Entry(this).Collection(t => t.Users).Load();
}
```

In all cases I get an exception that the property `Users` on entity `Tag` is not a valid navigation property. (The exception disappears as soon as I make the property `public`.)

I don't know if adding/removing/updating relationships would work. (I doubt.)

It looks that you can map a non-public navigation property with this approach to generate the expected database schema. But it seems that there is nothing useful you can do with it.

Comment: I want to reach for a solution using DataAnnotation. I didn't yet tried Data Migrations with Fluent APIs and not sure if it will work.

Comment: Code First never maps private or internal members by default. You must use the fluent API to map them, as @Slauma showed. You cannot do this with data annotations. However, once you map the property using the fluent API, then any data annotation on that property will be respected. So, for example, if you added a MaxLength attribute to a private property then it still would not be included in the model. But if you also used the fluent API to map the property, then the MaxLength attribute would be read and used.

Comment: Using Fluent API you can map internal properties in Code First. I've tried that and it works for ages now. For protected members you need to do what @Slauma specified above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about EF5 but you can use the attribute [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z5024a8.aspx) to make internal members visible to a specific assembly.